# Javascript find all combinations in order for numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assume I've got an array:

```
var arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3];
```

I need to compute all unique possible combinations ***in order*** out of this array that use the most numbers possible, provided each is unique. I don't care so much about the values but instead a matrix of indices that match:

```
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
```

I looked at [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52126), however when I do that:

```
var arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3];
console.log(allPossibleCases(arr));
```

I get:

```
["1 1 2 3 3"]
```

Which does make sense according to what that function does, but I've been unable to tweak it enough to suit what I want.

Edit:

Note the part where I said **IN ORDER**. This is not a complete set of permutations and none of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908) do what I'm asking.

Comment: you just need do a bit preparation for calling `allPossibleCases` - from this `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3]` do array `[[0,1],2,[3,4]]`. You can do this with `Array.reduce` function

Comment: No, @Alexander I specifically said IN ORDER. This is not a complete set of permutations.

Comment: @Grundy not sure how `Array.reduce()` translates to that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: sure, something like this `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3].reduce(function(acc,el,index){
    var cur = acc.map[el];
    if(!cur) {
        acc.map[el] = cur = [];
        acc.res.push(cur);
    }
    cur.push(index);
    return acc;
},{res:[],map:{}}).res` moved `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3]` to `[[0,1],[2],[3,4]]`

Comment: Slick @Grundy! If you want to slap that in as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using function from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52119/calculate-all-possible-combinations-of-an-array-of-arrays-or-strings/52126#52126) you just need a bit prepare your array with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) something like this

```
var prepared = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3].reduce(function(acc,el,index){
    var cur = acc.map[el]; 
    if(!cur) { 
        acc.map[el] = cur = []; 
        acc.res.push(cur); 
    } 
    cur.push(index); 
    return acc; 
},{res:[],map:{}}).res;
```

and `prepared` looks like `[[0,1],[2],[3,4]]`

here just group index for duplicated items.